# How do I insert data into my mySql database using parameters in a URL?

Tags: database

I am new to PHP and databases, here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

$email = $_POST['Email'];
$tc = $_POST['TotalCash'];
$tr = $_POST['TotalReferalls'];

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("205.178.146.92", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserInformation(Email, TotalCash, TotalReferalls) VALUES('$email', '$tc', '$tr')"); 
Print "Your table has been populated"; 
?>
```

and this works when I change `$email` and all of the variables to a set value, like `$email = 'bob@aol.com'`, `$tc = 3`, `$tr = 4`, but when I try to set it by calling a url (mysite.com/myphp.php?$email='blah@aol.com'&$tc=4&$tr=2) it does not work, please show a working way to set the parameters from the url.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parameters from the URL, switch `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Also, you will need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with those outside strings, otherwise you have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Even better, because you are new to PHP and databases, learn it the best way from the start. Drop `mysql_*()` and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

For URl, you have to change $_POST to $_GET.