# Inserting multiple rows into database through a link

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am quite new in php and mysql. 
I was trying to insert multiple (unknown ) number of rows into mysql database. The data is posted into the table through a link - 
http://localhost:81/logdata.php?CtrlID=3842&DateTime=2017-05-18+11%3A45%3A23&Bat=50.2&LVSD=1&Indt=29.4&Outdt=32.8&submit

The following code works perfect as long as a single row is posted. But I have no idea how to insert several rows together and how 
the link should look like.  Actually rows containing data are formed and stored in a Microcontroller. 
I am  sending the data with the help of GPRS. The controller successfully sending one row at a time, the data is correctly recorded in
mysql database. But I am struggling to send several rows together. I would highly appreciate any suggestion.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; //your pwd
$dbname = "mirzu";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
if($conn){
    echo 'Successfully Connected database.';
     }

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//if(isset($_GET['submit'])){   //
    $ID = $_GET['CtrlID'];
    $DateTime = $_GET['DateTime'];
    $battery = $_GET['Bat'];
    $LVSD = $_GET['LVSD'];
    $IndoorT = $_GET['Indt'];
    $OutdoorT = $_GET['Outdt'];

$totalCtrlID = sizeof($ID);

for($i=0;$i<$totalCtrlID;$i++) {

    $InsCtrlID = [$ID][$i]; 
    $InsDateTime = [$DateTime][$i];
    $Insbattery = [$battery][$i];
    $InsLVSD = [$LVSD][$i];
    $InsIndoorT = [$IndoorT][$i];
    $InsOutdoorT = [$OutdoorT][$i];


 $query = "INSERT INTO btsdata (CtrlID,DateTime,Batt,LVSD,IndT,OutdT)". 
"VALUES  ('$InsCtrlID','$InsDateTime','$Insbattery','$InsLVSD','$InsIndoorT','$InsOutdoorT');";

}

if (mysqli_query($conn,  $query)) {
    echo "New record created successfully into database";
} else {
    echo "Error: " .  $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
//}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to insert values to database from $_GET. And to trust user input in general. Read about SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks, GET will be replaced with POST, not a big problem. But my main problem is now inserting multiple rows with one posting.

Comment: Answer provided by @Bhupesh Kushwaha is what you looking for. Other topic, you used in here a lot of bad practises. You should always, validate data, before infect to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Two records the query will become:

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE (column1, column2) VALUES ('data', 'data'), ('data', 'data')
```

Same as a more than two record.

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_name
        (a,b,c)
    VALUES
        (1,2,3),
        (4,5,6),
        (7,8,9);
```

Comment: Bhupesh Kushwaha, thanks for the answer. The main issues actually are, the total number of row  is unknown and the data will be posted through a link as I have mentioned at the beginning of my post.  timiTao, sorry for the 'bad practices', I am completely new in php. Hope to improve gradually.

Comment: The data needs to come from a remote location through GPRS Modem.  Bhupesh, could you please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: tell me one thing CtrlID=3842&DateTime=2017-05-18+11%3A45%3A23&Bat=50.2&LVSD=1&Indt=29.4&Outdt=32.8 its repeated or not CtrlID,DateTime ..

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your question. Here the CtriID=3842 is a constant number, all others are variables recorded in one row in the controller in 1 minutes interval. After 15 minutes or so the GPRS modem sends the records to the URL at a time. The number of records may increase if the modem fails to communicate, will automatically retry after 15 minutes, but the number of rows will increase.

Comment: @mainul can you share those url

Comment: I am really in  desperate need for a solution. I am struggling for a week or so to find out the answer.  Well, I understand  from a discussion that I have to use 'GET' and not 'POST' to insert data through URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352368/how-do-i-insert-data-into-my-mysql-database-using-parameters-in-a-url